# In-text citation formatting with custom .bst (Lyx)

Tags: lyx

I have read through some related threads on this but cannot seem to find an answer that works for me. I use a custom .bst file, not natbib, and would like my in-text citations to be Author-Year in format. What I see instead upon generating the pdf is indeed Author-Year, but it is the author's full name (as in, e.g., 'David Armstrong 1981'.

What I would like to have appear is 'Armstrong 1981'. I use Lyx and when setting the citation style I have "Author-Year" selected. Things just aren't showing up that way for me in the .pdf.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and include your custom .bst file?